# yii relations on multiple database connections

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I am using two database connections in Yii. 
One contains a table with the office name that I would like to be able to use as a related field for a model in a different database in a grid-view so the filters will work

I have used virtual attributes and a get method which will give me the name I require in the grid . However the filter does not work.

Is there a way to use relations in the model with multiple databases ?
Or is there something I can put in the search method that will work ?

Answer (score 0):

Never tried it but you can setup [multiple databases](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/123/multiple-database-support-in-yii/) and you can choose which db connection to use for each model.
I guess you cannot use the relation mapping like you can with only one connection, but you can define your own getter in your model, which simply queries the other db.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried this and it works ( in the question I point out that I am using multiple connections and have tried virtual attributes) , my only issue is getting the filter working on a grid view- I believe it needs to be something in the criteria in the model's search function, but cant get it to work

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I misunderstood your question. With grid view and virtual attributes/getters you cannot use a active dataprovider, which goes straight to the db, therefore not using your getters. You can however use an array data provider which does use virtual attributes and getters, but performance might go down for large table data.